# UIButton isn't responding to my touches on collectionView cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I'm creating collectionView and inside that in every cell I'm creating few buttons horizontally but those buttons aren't responding to my target selector.

Here is my code.

ImplementationView.h

```
-(IBAction)tagClicked:(UIButton*)sender;
```

In ImplementationView.m

```
-(void)configureScrapCell:(UICollectionViewCell*) cell forScrapDict:(ScrapDictionary *)dict forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*){

UIView *tagView = (UIView*)[cell viewWithTag:17];
UIView *layerTagView = (UIView*)[cell viewWithTag:18];
CGFloat x = 0.0;

if (layerTagView) {
    [layerTagView removeFromSuperview];
  }
   layerTagView = [[UIView alloc] init];
   layerTagView.tag = 18;
   [tagView addSubview:layerTagView];

   if ([dict.SDtags count]>0) {
        int tagIndex = 1;
        for (NSString *tag in dict.SDtags) {
            CGSize width = [tag sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
                UIButton *scrapTag = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0,100, 30)];
        [scrapTag setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [scrapTag.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    //  [scrapTag setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
    if (brightness > 150) {
         [scrapTag setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }else {        
         [scrapTag setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
         [scrapTag setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" #%@",tag] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //   [scrapTag sizeToFit];

         [scrapTag setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
         tagIndex++;
         NSString *tagString = @"";
         tagString = [tagString stringByAppendingString:tag];
         if ([tagString length]>32 || tagIndex>4) {
            break;
       }
 [scrapTag addTarget:self action:@selector(tagClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [layerTagView addSubview:scrapTag];
    NSLog(@"%f",scrapTag.frame.size.width);
    //  scrapTag.frame = CGRectMake(x, scrapTag.frame.origin.y, tagView.frame.size.width, 30);
                x += scrapTag.frame.size.width +2; 
            }
        }
         [tagView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:0.5]];
        [layerTagView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:0.5]];
```

Now in different class where I'm defining the action of these button Clicked. ImplementationView class is acting as delegate for NewClass.

NewClass.h

```
#import ImplementationView.h
@interface NewClass : ImplementationView
```

NewClass.m

```
-(IBAction)tagClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"LOL" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sender.titleLabel.text] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show ];

    NSLog(@"testing tag clicked");
}
```

Let me know if you need any other help to make question clear. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You sure you don't have conflicts of gestureRecognizers ?

Comment: Yeah.. I don't have conflicts with gestureRecognisers, I just figured out the issue, I'm using these lines... 
if (layerTagView) {
   [layerTagView removeFromSuperview];
  }
   layerTagView = [[UIView alloc] init];
   layerTagView.tag = 18;
   [tagView addSubview:layerTagView];
to avoid overlapping of text but actualview is removed so I'm not able to click it.

Answer (score 1):

Your buttons are not on the layerTagView bounds.
You need to set layerTagView frame/size. In your code the size of layerTagView is (0,0).
For check my suggestions you can set masksToBounds to YES or change the background color for layerTagView to blue or any other color.

```objc
tagView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
layerTagView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```